# ListView внутри Fragment

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

В программе используется активити типа `fixed tabs + swipe`. В одном из фрагментов размещен `listView`, который должен подключатся к базе данных `SQLite`. Поскольку опыта у меня маловато, то я грешным делом пробовал описать подключение к `БД` прямо в методе `OnCreateView()` в классе фрагмента. Увы безрезультатно. Потом пробовал вынести в отдельный метод - то же самое, я получаю пустой `listView`. `БД` не пустая.

Код класса фрагмента:

```
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }
    View v;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tracker,
                container, false);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tracker,
                container, false);
        createList();

        return rootView;
    }

    public void createList(){
        db = new DB(act);
        db.open();
        String[] from = new String[] {DB.COLUMN_NAME, DB.COLUMN_TIME};
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.tvTextName, R.id.tvText_time};

        Cursor cursor = db.getAllData();

        scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.item, cursor, from, to, 0);
        lvData = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lvData);
        lvData.setAdapter(scAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

просили закрутить курсор в цикле и вывести в логи вот цикл:

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
        for(int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++){
            Log.d(TAG,"курсор: " + cursor.getString(0)+" "+cursor.getString(1)+" "+cursor.getString(2));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
```

И сами логи:

```
04-05 11:35:41.824: D/dalvikvm(2028): Late-enabling CheckJNI
04-05 11:35:41.912: D/dalvikvm(2028): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 107K, 6% free 2873K/3036K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
04-05 11:35:41.928: D/Data Base(2028): Открытие Подключения
04-05 11:35:41.932: D/Data Base(2028): Подключение открыто
04-05 11:35:41.932: D/Data Base(2028): Получение данных таблицы...
04-05 11:35:41.932: D/MainActivity(2028): курсор: 1 Пример Категории 1 00:00:0
04-05 11:35:41.932: D/MainActivity(2028): курсор: 2 Пример Категории 2 00:00:0
04-05 11:35:41.932: D/MainActivity(2028): курсор: 3 Пример Категории 3 00:00:0
04-05 11:35:41.932: D/MainActivity(2028): курсор: 4 Пример Категории 4 00:00:0
04-05 11:35:41.932: D/MainActivity(2028): курсор: 5 Пример Категории 5 00:00:0
04-05 11:35:41.932: D/MainActivity(2028): курсор: 6 Пример Категории 6 00:00:0
04-05 11:35:41.932: D/MainActivity(2028): курсор: 7 Пример Категории 7 00:00:0
04-05 11:35:41.932: D/MainActivity(2028): курсор: 8 Пример Категории 8 00:00:0
04-05 11:35:41.932: D/MainActivity(2028): курсор: 9 Пример Категории 9 00:00:0
04-05 11:35:41.932: D/MainActivity(2028): курсор: 10 Пример Категории 10 00:00:0
04-05 11:35:41.956: D/libEGL(2028): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
04-05 11:35:41.960: D/(2028): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb836f8d0, tid 2028
04-05 11:35:41.964: D/libEGL(2028): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
04-05 11:35:41.964: D/libEGL(2028): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
04-05 11:35:41.984: W/EGL_genymotion(2028): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-05 11:35:41.984: E/OpenGLRenderer(2028): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
04-05 11:35:41.988: E/OpenGLRenderer(2028): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
04-05 11:35:41.988: D/OpenGLRenderer(2028): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Comment: вы создали rootView и вернули его. а listView найти пытаетесь в v. это два разных объекта, v - фантом (он существует, но в активити не добавляется), rootView - реальный view, который добавлен в активити. избавьтесь от одного из них.

Comment: Спасибо дружище! оно работает!

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте работу базы данных хотя бы в логах, я бы рекомендовал вынести работу с бд в отдельный класс  ─ отдельно helper, отдельно класс который  будет будет работать с бд и отдельно класс модели, вопрос предпочтений,но  мне такая архитектура работы с бд наиболее удобна, при необходимости добавить провайдер... вопрос личных предпочтений, но мне кажется у Вас проблема при работе с бд.

Comment: Поподробнее если можно. База данных у меня находится в отдельном файле там же и находится ДБ хэлпер. БД работает корректно, запускал приложение на эмуляторе, потом заходил через root explorer в директорию программы - база данных успешно создана и заполнена так как я запрограммировал. Но вот list view напрочь отказывается ее показывать. Ребята из stackoverflow.com, советовали обратить внимание на v.findViewById. так как по из мнению оно возвращает нуль, я проверял - вроде все норм

Comment: проверьте правильно ли работает запрос ─то что в курсоре, на первый взгляд должно работать

Comment: если нужно могу кинуть код БД но он взят из предыдущей версии приложения и полностью рабочий

Comment: проверил так: if (cursor.getCount() != 0)Log.d(TAG, "курсор не пустой"); срабатывает.

Comment: проблема так же может быть в том что я не добавил создания лоадера: 
getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);. Он был у меня в основном классе активити и не срабатывал. Сейчас я его добавил в класс фрагмент. компилятор ругается: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getSupportLoaderManager() from the type FragmentActivity"

Comment: Просто пробегитесь в цикле по всем элементам курсора, просто посмотрите что у вас там по ключам, по сути то что у вас должно работать, ради теста можно даже просто в массив загнать данные из курсора и просмотреть что выведет, то что в курсоре что то есть хорошо, но то ли это что вам нужно ...